# Search for Multiple Substring Possibilities in a Column: Google Sheets

Tags: search, google-sheets, substring

Column A contains roughly 3,000 cells with long text strings in each. Somewhere in those long text strings are names listed in Column C (~800 names).

I am attempting to write a formula that will search each cell in column A for one of those names in column C. When it finds one of those names, it should pull that name into column B.

Here is a link to an example in Google Sheets.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O87OkQdkfSo5N8WjiqcL5YZfLiyaeds3YAXclVQS_2Q/edit#gid=0

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "I will pull the ID associated with that row" does this refer to column A or B? Where is the ID information located? (is it a separate column or just the row number?)

Comment: That's probably unnecessary information, sorry about that. I just want to know if there is a way to do the first part. Once I can write a formula to search through long text strings (COL A) for possible names (COL B), the rest will be easy.

Comment: Totally do-able. But it's always hard not to mention inefficient to try to write formulas for data and layouts we can't see. Believe it or not, there are lots of unknown factors that could affect how I'd write this. The most efficient and effective means of receiving fast help is to share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it, or a realistic representative sample from it), being sure to set that link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll put together some similar example data and add the link in the comments here.

Comment: Add the link as an edit to your question. Its better to keep all the question in the post itself.

Comment: I just updated and added an example sheet, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the [MATCH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) formula?

Comment: I am sorry I do not follow. Can MATCH be used to look at a list of names and check if one of those names exist in a (seemingly random) string of text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in each row of column B. Keep in mind that you should have good (well structured) data in column A. As the formula searcheds for the substring that comes between "Name=" and "," to find a match in the NameList list.

> `=VLOOKUP(index(split(index(Split(B3,"Name=",FALSE),2),",",FALSE),1),NameList!A2:A,1)`

#### References:

- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for putting this together. Unfortunately the names in the data I have does not always come after 'name=', sometimes it just seems to be floating in a short paragraph of text